# C# email to gmail marked spam but from thunderbird client are delivered as normal (non-spam)

Tags: c#, email, smtp, spam

I've a small vps where is installed mailenable mailserver.
I've already checked PTR , reverse DNS and server configuration, all is ok.

If i send an email from Thunderbird to a gmail address all is ok and the mail is not marked as spam, this is the header:

```
Delivered-To: antani2@gmail.com
Received: by 10.60.38.104 with SMTP id f8csp54812oek;
Fri, 18 May 2012 13:04:27 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.216.138.130 with SMTP id a2mr7849178wej.35.1337371466927;
Fri, 18 May 2012 13:04:26 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <mailrobot@charterino.com>
Received: from mail.charterino.com (mail.charterino.com. [95.110.146.72])
by mx.google.com with ESMTP id m60si12747577wee.64.2012.05.18.13.04.26;
Fri, 18 May 2012 13:04:26 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of mailrobot@charterino.com designates 95.110.146.72 as permitted sender) client-ip=95.110.146.72;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of mailrobot@charterino.com designates 95.110.146.72 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=mailrobot@charterino.com
Received: from [192.168.1.132] ([2.227.153.144]) by charterino.com with MailEnable ESMTP; Fri, 18 May 2012 22:01:40 +0200
Message-ID: <4FB6AB4A.8000508@charterino.com>
Date: Fri, 18 May 2012 22:04:26 +0200
From: "mailrobot@charterino.com" <mailrobot@charterino.com>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20120428 Thunderbird/12.0.1
MIME-Version: 1.0
To: antani2@gmail.com
Subject: Prova
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-15; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

When i send an email from a c# application my message is marked as spam, this is the header:

```
Delivered-To: antani@gmail.com
Received: by 10.229.39.205 with SMTP id h13csp119310qce;
Fri, 18 May 2012 12:09:26 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.180.82.136 with SMTP id i8mr4157077wiy.19.1337368166529;
Fri, 18 May 2012 12:09:26 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <mailrobot@charterino.com>
Received: from mail.charterino.com (mail.charterino.com. [95.110.146.72])
by mx.google.com with ESMTP id h11si2000858wiw.14.2012.05.18.12.09.26;
Fri, 18 May 2012 12:09:26 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of mailrobot@charterino.com designates 95.110.146.72 as permitted sender) client-ip=95.110.146.72;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of mailrobot@charterino.com designates 95.110.146.72 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=mailrobot@charterino.com
Message-Id: <4fb69e66.2b4cb40a.29ee.ffffa974SMTPIN_ADDED@mx.google.com>
Received: from win18864 ([::1]) by charterino.com with MailEnable ESMTP; Fri, 18 May 2012 21:06:44 +0200
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: mailrobot@charterino.com
To: antani@gmail.com
```

This could be caused by the messageid that is not containing the domain @charterino.com?
I've tried also to override the message-id in the mail headers from my app but the server overwrite it.

```
message.Headers.Add("Message-Id","<values>@charterino.com");
```

I don't know if it is the problem but....why thunderbird can overwrite the message-id and i can't??

I'm using System.Net.Mail.

Any idea??

After adding the "date" and the "subject" field this is the new header, added with

```
message.Headers.Add(String.format("<date format>",DateTime.Now.ToString()));

Delivered-To: antani@gmail.com
Received: by 10.229.39.205 with SMTP id h13csp155984qce;
        Sat, 19 May 2012 06:20:49 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.216.138.130 with SMTP id a2mr9265313wej.35.1337433648907;
        Sat, 19 May 2012 06:20:48 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <mailrobot@charterino.com>
Received: from mail.charterino.com (mail.charterino.com. [95.110.146.72])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id p8si14856169weh.0.2012.05.19.06.20.48;
        Sat, 19 May 2012 06:20:48 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of mailrobot@charterino.com designates 95.110.146.72 as permitted sender) client-ip=95.110.146.72;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of mailrobot@charterino.com designates 95.110.146.72 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=mailrobot@charterino.com
Message-Id: <4fb79e30.8878d80a.4344.ffff961dSMTPIN_ADDED@mx.google.com>
Received: from win18864 ([::1]) by charterino.com with MailEnable ESMTP; Sat, 19 May 2012 15:18:08 +0200
Subject: Invio password smarrita Charterino.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: mailrobot@charterino.com
To: antani@gmail.com
Date: 19 May 2012 15:18:08 +0200
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

nothing change, the mail is marked spam.

Comment: What SMTP server is Thunderbird using?  What SMTP server is your application using?

Comment: @robert, they appear to be the same: `mail.charterino.com (mail.charterino.com. [95.110.146.72])`

Comment: Are you sending same content ? All other things being equal, content would be the cause for being marked as spam.

Comment: Also the content of the mail is the same.

Comment: Looks like they're going to 2 different email addresses?

Comment: Your attempted Message-Id value is incorrect; try with `<value@domain>` instead of the syntactically invalid `<value>@domain` you had. I don't think this will make ir break the spam filter, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
message.IsBodyHtml = true; 
message.Body = htmlView;
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the "Date:" field from the headers.

Comment: this is the new header, i've add by hand the date with:

Comment: added , nothing changed, in the question i update with the new header

Comment: OK, the next suspect is the content type. Do you really have html? In your first example you have 7bit ascii.

Comment: Thanks for the -1. These are all issues which spam filters consider. BTW: if you want to do a fair comparison, you would use the same Subject in both. And content type was only revealed in the edited headers.